# What does @ prefix means?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell, plutus-playground, plutustx

like this:

```
auctionInstance = Scripts.validator @Auctioning
```

and Hello-world app from https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/tutorial/tutorials/plutus-playground.html#running-the-hello-world-app

```
hello = logInfo @String "Hello, world"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means [type application](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/type-application).

In this case, the function is polymorphic with the following type:

```
logInfo :: forall a effs. Member (LogMsg a) effs => a -> Eff effs ()
```

by using [TypeApplications](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html) extension, you can use `@SomeType` hint for the compiler, so the `logInfo` call is not ambiguous.

`logInfo @String "Hello world"` means apply type `String` to functions type variable `a` (the order depends on the order of type variables in explicit `forall` section - `forall a effs` - sometimes you may want to add multiple hints e.g. `convert @String @Text someArg otherArg`).

Ambiguity here stems from multiple string types in Haskell so you need to tell the compiler which type you are using (`String`, `Text` or`ByteString`).